# Lightning Component to search layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, quickaction

I have a lightning component that redirect to an external url. I need to use that component as an action in my list views. How do i implement this. I know actions can be put on the list views using search layouts, but when i am creating an action using lightning component i am unable to get the action in search layout in the column

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't call a lightning component as part of list actions. You will have to go [visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_actions.htm) route(I'm not sure about Lightning component in a vfp but its worth giving a try). What your're looking for is in [salesforce future road map](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_roadmap.htm&type=0).

For reference look at [Lightning quick Action in the List view](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224538/lightning-quick-action-in-the-list-view)

Comment: thank you for the information. Can u suggest a work around for getting a button or action to the list view that redirects to an external link by any means??

Comment: @SmrutiRanjanBiswal Your're welcome. You can use a vfpage [Standard list controller] button and redirect where you want(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_actions.htm)