# Lightning Action on List View (Multiple Records Selected)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I've found it difficult to find a recent answer to the question: Is it possible yet to perform mass updates to records on a list view using Lightning Components?

Essentially, I want users to be able to select multiple records in a List View, click a button, and have a Lightning Component process each and update a picklist value.

I know this is possible (and well documented) using Visualforce and the Standard Controller / extensions, but curious if there is a way to do so using Lightning Components (or even Lightning Web Components) yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this method but from an earlier answer posted might help - [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224538/lightning-quick-action-in-the-list-view)

> You can use the "lightning:isUrlAddressable" to access a lightning
>   component using an url and create a "List Button" with behavior as
>   "Display in existing window without sidebar or header" that directs
>   you to the component URL, as mentioned in the documentation:
>
> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation
>
> The URL in the list button should look like below:
>
> `{!URLFOR('/lightning/cmp/namespace__componentName', null,
>   [param=value])}`

Comment: I have tried this, but the selected record ids are not receiving in state__c.

See the page reference object that I received :

page reference {"type":"standard__component","attributes":{"componentName":"c__cc_ltngMassAccept"},"state":{"uid":"1606769100291"}}

Could you please help on this? Am I missing anything?

Comment: I have found [this](https://codingwiththeforce.com/salesforce-development-tutorial-lwc-how-to-use-lightning-web-components-in-list-view-buttons/), maybe it helps.